# Hardware Upgrade for Sybase ASE

Tags: performance, sybase-ase-15.7

We are upgrading our hardware for Sybase ASE and minor upgrade in the Sybase ASE Service Pack Version.

Upgrades are as follows:

1.Number of Cores - From 4 core to 8 core

2.Physical memory - 64 GB to 128GB.

3.ASE - Upgraded from "Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 21707 SMP SP110 /P/ia64/HP-UX B.11.31/ase157sp11x/3546/64-bit/FBO/Fri Nov 8 08:40:39 2013" to "Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 27351 SMP SP139 /P/ia64/HP-UX B.11.31/ase157sp138x/4041/64-bit/FBO/Tue Aug 8 07:33:11 2017"

I have configured number of engines from 4 to 8 and max memory from 60GB to 100GB.

can someone please advise what additional parameters should be changed in order to enhance performance of Sybase on the new server

Comment: depends on the root cause of any performance issues you may be having; if queries are performing table scans because of a missing index, no amount of tuning is going to help (though if you can place the whole table in memory that could eliminate any physical IOs); if a query has a poor query plan due to datatype mismatches between a pair of join columns, no amount of tuning is going to help; if all of your data could fit into memory with the old configurations, additional memory will just be wasted; so ...why did you think more memory was needed? what performance problems are you having?

Comment: HP-UX. Wow, that takes me back to the 20th century

Comment: HP-UX was suggested by vendor at that time, we didn't have any expert on operating system then; so, whatever they suggested, my organization had to go for it :)